# scalaz-stream consume stream based on computed value

Tags: scala, scalaz-stream

I've got two streams and I want to be able to consume only one based on a computation that I run every `x` seconds.

I think I basically need to create a third `tick` stream - something like `every(3.seconds)` - that does the computation and then come up with sort of a switch between the other two.

I'm kind of stuck here (and I've only just started fooling around with scalaz-stream).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways we can approach this problem. One way to approach it is using `awakeEvery`. For concrete example, see [here](https://github.com/adilakhter/scalaitaly-functional-stream-processing).

To describe the example briefly, consider that we would like to query twitter in every 5 sec and get the tweets and perform sentiment analysis. We can compose this pipeline as follows:

```scala
val source = 
    awakeEvery(5 seconds) |> buildTwitterQuery(query) through queryChannel flatMap {
        Process emitAll _ 
    }
```

Note that the `queryChannel` can be stated as follows.

```scala
def statusTask(query: Query): Task[List[Status]] = Task {
      twitterClient.search(query).getTweets.toList
}

val queryChannel: Channel[Task, Query, List[Status]] = channel lift statusTask
```

Let me know if you have any question. As stated earlier, for the complete example, see [this](https://github.com/adilakhter/scalaitaly-functional-stream-processing).

I hope it helps!